# Does an additional "AND `columnname` LIKE '%'" hurt performance?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

simple question: Does adding something like this to a query hurt performance in mysql or does it quickly get optimized away?

```
AND `name` LIKE '%'
```

I've got no big database here that I could test it on.

By the way, I want this because I want users to be able to send some parameters to my server-side script that then grabs the prepared statement specified by the user and inserts the parameters. I want users to be able to omit parameters when searching without hurting the performance, and `LIKE` normally is relatively slow, right?

Comment: @Karl: From my question: "I've got no big database here that I could test it on."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LIKE's can be expensive indeed, depending on the indexes you have on the `name` field. Have you tried to measure your query?

```
EXPLAIN [EXTENDED] SELECT [...] AND `name` LIKE '%'
```

See also http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html

Then MySQL will give you indications whether it has optimised the unnecessary LIKE clause away or not.

Comment: The question is if LIKE '%' (match anything) will be removed by the query analyzer. (I am not sure how LIKE '%' works with NULL values).

Comment: `type` is `ALL` and `possible_keys` is `NULL`. And it also returns rows where the value is `NULL`. Thanks, this answered my question and I learned how to do it the next time. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  LIKE's are very expensive.  But as with most things, it depends on the size of your DB.

Comment: Yeah, but watch the fine print LIKE '%' would not eliminate anything, so it might get optimized out.  I was about to post the same thing as you when I realized that as well.  My THEORY is that it probably would, but I have no means of testing.

Comment: Gotcha...  It is going to depend entirely on the DB code.  Someone *might* have added an optimization for that, but why rely upon it.  It can't be that hard to remove that clause yourself, right?

Comment: Well, I'm currently developing a web application and the server-side code is in PHP (for compatibility and because I don't want to do much server-side), and I wouldn't like to build some unnecessary-clause-removing function when the DB already does it for me.

Answer (score 0):

`LIKE` can definately hurt performance.  The most important thing to check is that you have the proper indexes.  What indexes do you have on the tables being queried?

I suspect that since your `LIKE` isn't actually doing anything it would just be optimized out but you will need to test to confirm this.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the previous answers: `LIKE` is pretty expensive. If your table is properly indexed, a small result-set can be *additionally* queried using `LIKE`.

In conjunction with `OR` the query is going to be brutally expensive again, though.

Also, solely using `LIKE` to query an indexed `VARCHAR` field should present minimal performance gain at best.

Answer (score -1):

Just tested with MySQL 5 using MyISAM tables.

```
SELECT * FROM tablename

17596 rows in set (0.28 sec)

SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE columnname LIKE '%'

17596 rows in set (0.20 sec)
```

Seems that MySQL query engine optimizes things like '0'='0' and LIKE '%' away.

Comment: Have you flushed the query cache before? I think not.

Comment: I don't see the relevance of query cache since those are queries that wouldn't be used in a production system.

Comment: +1 @gore.  Those results definitely look like the results of a warmed cache.

Comment: What about the generated query plans? One-off "run speeds" themselves are quite boring and the second "speedup" may simply be due to a hotter cache, etc. (E.g. would this hold on a very large table? Looking at the query plans will tell more.)

Comment: I don't see what a warmed cache has to do with it??? The question is whether MySQL evaluates the statement `AND blah LIKE '%'`.

Comment: @Novikov If these are two identical queries performed on a system otherwise unoccupied how do you explain the difference then?

Comment: @pst: I'm not suggesting that using the LIKE query sped it up. It's quite obvious that second time around the entire table is in memory. However it also shows that the LIKE clause was never evaluated since that'd take several times longer than the simple query.